# Not all events exporting from firebase to biqquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Events from app is begin displayed correctly in my app but is not displayed when query my BigQuery table for the same data.

The app remove event for 10 September 2021 have the count of 449 in Firebase analytics but in BigQuery it is only showing as 4. Below are the screenshots:

[image: Firebase Screenshot]

[image: BigQuery Screenshot]

BigQuery query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `applied-buckeye.analytics_153.events_20210910`
WHERE
  event_name="app_remove"
```

Comment: When did you enable BigQuery Linking in GA? Was it before 10.09.2021?

Comment: Yes it was before 10.09.2021. I did it on 08.05.2021.
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/F0Q8Voa)